# Collaborative tagging app

Tags: web-apps, collaboration

I have a bunch of product reviews that I would like to collaboratively tag with my colleagues.

I am looking for collaborative tagging Web app that:

- everyone can tag a text with a free-text tag
- everyone can see other peoples tags about a given text
- everyone can search reviews/texts by both tag and phrase in the text
- by clicking a tag under a text I can see other texts tagged with the same tag
- source code is open so I can modify it
- I can host it on my laptop
- is free

Reviewed tools:

- [Label Studio](https://github.com/heartexlabs/label-studio) is an example of annotation tool for many purposes, including NLP tasks. It's great tool for manually classifying text according to some predefined vocabulary or taxonomy but does not offer is a way to search/filter by tags, see other user tags.
- [del.icio.us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delicious_(website)) was a social bookmarking service that allowed to tag collaborative URLs. It is closed to what I expected, althought it was about tagging URLs, while I want to tag texts.

Comment: Can you tell us what are the drawbacks of the products you have reviewed?

Comment: @Josem I've added two I've seen so far. Will give more after the weekend. Thanks.